# Acumatica: CSV Data provider - Ignore lines in header

Tags: csv, acumatica

I have a file with payment info from a PSP an would like to use an Import scenario for this.

Problem is, the file includes a header before the actual column headings. Could you ignore the first lines in some way?

File header and column headers below:

Transaktionsrapport (): Debiterade transaktioner

Rapporten genererades:  16/11-2017 kl. 04:25:07

Transaktionsperiod:
  Startdatum: 15/11-2017 kl. 00:00:00 
  Slutdatum: 15/11-2017 kl. 23:59:59

Ordernr,Transaktionsnr,Belopp i SEK ,Belopp,Valuta,Avgift,Korttyp,Tidpunkt f�r auktorisation,Debiteringstidpunkt,Tidpunkt f�r �terbetalning,Avtal,Orderinformation
187411_171115064526,196621321,5450.00,3210.00,752,0.00,MC(SE),15/11-2017 kl. 06:46:51 ,15/11-2017 kl. 06:49:17 ,,EULI,

Answer (score 0):

There is a skip headers functionality when Import Scenario is consumed.

Is this something you can use to resolve your issue?

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I don´t think that will solve the issue. If I can't ignore the header in the Data provider it's not possible to find the columns (values) in the "Import by scenario" step.